# App is taking too long to run and install on Device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an app which im developing for quite some time. I am experiencing weird behavior, that when i run on Simulator, its takes few seconds, but when i run on Device or "Build for Archive" or "Archive", the progress bar slowly moves on until its about 94-95% near completion and stops there for about 5-7 mins. I am using Developers profile for provisioning. What could be the issue?

I have about 200 images in resources. But i dont think its too much and not normal for a big app. The IPA size is about 9.4 MB, and complete package size is about 40MB.

Comment: You can expect this to take a good while to install over a 3G connection as well.

Comment: Well, if you have a hunch about it being the images making it slow, test your hunch: half the amount of images in the build and time it. If it breaks the actual app, that doesn't matter, you're just testing the build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device would do a I/O operation for every file, so it will takes more time for 200 1M' files then one 200M's file .